# can not word with the insert query to insert id using php

Tags: php, mysql, insert-update

i have 2 tables

## district

- district_id
- district_name

## and village

- id
- village _name
- district_id

  i want to insert values to the table  .. the query work well with insert the value of the village table  but the district_ do not get the value of the id inserted in the district table instead it display 0.

can anyone help me ????

## code:

```
if(isset($_POST['add']))
   {
       if  ((!isset($_POST['city']) || $_POST['city'] == "") 
           && (!isset($_POST['lat'])|| $_POST['lat'] == "" )
           && (!isset($_POST['long'])|| $_POST['long'] == ""))
       {
         $errorMSG = "you must fill one of these fields befor you submit!!";
       }
      /* 
       if($_POST['gov'])
       {
           $gov = $_POST['gov'];
           $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO governorate (governorate_id, governorate_name)VALUES('', '$gov')")or die(mysql_error());
           echo $gov;
       }
       //******for adding district*********************
       elseif($_POST['dist'])
       {
           $dist = $_POST['dist'];
           $gov = $_POST['gov']; 
           if($gov)
           {
           $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO districts (district_id, district_name, governorate_id)VALUES('', '$dist', '$gov')")or die(mysql_error());

           $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO governorate (governorate_id, governorate_name)VALUES('', '$gov')") or die(mysql_error());

           echo $dist;
           }
           else{ $errorMSG = "You can not add District Without relate a Governorate for this district";}
       }
       */
       //********************for adding city****************************//

     if($_POST['city'])
       {
           $city = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['city']);
           $lat = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['lat']);
           $long = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['long']);
           $dist = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dist']); 
           $gov = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['gov']);
           if(!$dist)
           {
               $errorMSG = "you can not add city without having relation with district";
           }
           elseif($lat =="" || $long ==""){ $errorMSG = "You can not add village Without its coordinations";}
           else
           {
               $sqld = mysql_query("INSERT INTO districts (district_id, district_name, governorate_id)VALUES('', '$dist', '$gov')") or die(mysql_error());
           $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO village (id, village_name, district_id, lattitude, longitude)VALUES('', '$city', '$dist' ,'$lat',  '$long')")or die(mysql_error());

           }
       }

   }
```

Comment: Have you verified that you are actually receiving a district ID in the POST data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this.

```
      $sqld = mysql_query("INSERT INTO districts (district_id, district_name, governorate_id)VALUES('', '$dist', '$gov')") or die(mysql_error());

      $dist_id = mysql_insert_id();

       $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO village (id, village_name, district_id, lattitude, longitude)VALUES('', '$city', '$dist_id' ,'$lat',  '$long')")or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: $dist = mysql_insert_id();this statment will insert the last id on the table of district ???    but i did used the variable    $dist  to sign it to the **($_POST['dist'])**

Comment: This will get the district id inserted from last query, then you can insert same value in village insert query.

Comment: use different variable for that then.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `AUTO_INCREMENT` this should fix your issue

```
INSERT INTO districts (district_name, governorate_id)VALUES('$dist', '$gov')
```

I would also advise adding some sor of protection agains injects

Answer (score 0):

You're inserting a district **name** into the district **ID** field. Since you're attempting to insert a random string into the ID (numeric... I hope), it adds a 0 instead.

You should find the last ID inserted in district_id field and insert that instead of $dist in your second insert.